# Is it grammatically correct for titles to not have punctuation?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, syntactic-analysis

I was wondering (for no particular reason), is it grammatically correct for titles, including, but not limited to, the ones of questions in the websites of the Stack Exchange network, to not have punctuation such as commas and full stop (period)?

My question is regarding the grammatical correctness of it, regardless of the importance to follow grammar or not in each circumstance.

Comment: It's not really a matter of grammar but of style.  And yes, titles can obey punctuation rules different from those obeyed by regular text - for example most daily newspapers in the UK omit all punctuation from headlines.  Unless it's a really good one deserving of multiple `!`s.

Comment: Punctuation isn't about grammar.

Comment: @tchrist Is there a name for the rules of punctuation? Any suggestion on what I should change in the question?

Comment: A title is not a sentence in written English. Titles do not have SVPs. (subject verb and predicate) **which is where punctuation is usually found** in written English.

Comment: I should say not that titles should have punctuation, but that they should not need punctuation unless there is an exceptionally strong reason for it.